# How can i insert and update document in two different databases at the same time in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to insert and update document in two different DB's in MongoDB.
is defining two connection string the solution.If Yes?,then how will the insert operation take place in both the databases?

Answer (score 0):

If your databases are similar you can set up replica set.
If the databases are different, the connections and insert operations up to your application code. Just use two connections and insert twice into different databases.

Comment: 1 DB is internal and other DB is on AWS. If i have to perform two different insertions do i need to perform throughout each and every insert query? I have around 200 different models.In each model insert and update needs to be performed is it a good practise?

Comment: Please clarify are the databases similar (different physically but similar by the structure)? In any case no matter how many models you need to persist. This is your business logic and you can do it.

Comment: yes the databases are similar by structure.I think so i need to perform insert in both the DB's.Thanks for your help :)

Comment: In this case you don't need to save your data twice in the code. You need just setup a replica set. MongoDB has the ability to replicate database automatically out of the box. You can use replicas in any data center you wish. Just read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/). Please be aware of your version of MongoDB.